# Add alternate numbers in a list<int> or vector<int>

Tags: c++, list, vector

I'm trying to access alternate numbers in a list to add their values. For, e.g. if a List has values = { 1, 2, 3, 5}. I should get the output, 4 and 7.

For this purpose, I'm using a std::List. First and foremost, I need to be able to access the Nth element of a sequence, `std::list` to be able to add the values. That said, I know that I can get an iterator to the Nth element using `std::advance`:

```
std::list<Object> l;

unsigned N = /* index of the element that I want to retrieve */;
if (l.size() > N)
{
    std::list<Object>::iterator it = l.begin();
    std::advance(it, N);
}
```

However, this does not solve my problem because I don't understand how to be able to access alternate values while adding them since it doesn't provide random access.

So, I tried using `std::vector` for which I was using

```
sum_of_vector =std::accumulate(vector.begin(),vector.end(),0);
```

This works well when I am adding all the values of the vector, but I don't understand the logic if I need to add only the alternate values of either `std::list` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just keep track of both running totals and just iterate over the collection once?

Comment: http://ideone.com/O9sZy6 check this.. Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

1. Create an array of two elements to accumulate the sums.
2. Use an index that alternates between `0` and `1`.

```
Object sum[2] = {0};
int index = 0;
auto iter = l.begin();
auto end = l.end();
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter, index = (index+1)%2 )
{
    sum[index] += *iter;
}
```

**Explanation of code, in response to OP's comment**

Let's take your list as an example:

```
l is {1, 2, 3, 5}
```

At the start of the `for` loop:

```
sum[0] = sum[1] = 0
index = 0
iter points to the element whose value is 1
```

When the loop gets executed,

```
sum[index] = sum[0] = 1
```

In the next iteration of the loop,

```
index = 1
iter points to the element whose value is 2
```

When the loop gets executed,

```
sum[index] = sum[1] = 2
```

In the next iteration of the loop,

```
index = 0
iter points to the element whose value is 3
```

When the loop gets executed,

```
sum[index] = sum[0] = 4
```

In the next iteration of the loop,

```
index = 1
iter points to the element whose value is 5
```

When the loop gets executed,

```
sum[index] = sum[1] = 7
```

In the next iteration of the loop,
    index = 0
    iter points to end. The loop execution stops.

At this point,

```
sum[0] = 4
sum[1] = 7
```

Comment: What is Object? Edit: Nvm.

Comment: @Daqs, if `sum` needs to be an array of `int`s or `double`s, it's not too hard to fix that :)

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm getting a syntax error: C2059: syntax error : ')' in the FOR loop

Comment: @Daqs, I had an error in the loop. I had `++iter;` instead of `++iter,`. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Your answer is definitely working really well. Thanks. Could you maybe explain the code? I don't understand how to access the sum, and how is it adding the alternate values. I'm sorry, I'm new to C++. I understood most of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82883/discussion-between-daqs-and-r-sahu).

Comment: @Daqs, I added detailed explanations of the code for benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2):

See the below code. I have added comments so that it would be self-explanatory.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    //Your vector of integers
    vector<int> V = {1, 2, 3, 5};

    //Size of your vector
    int n = V.size();

    //Initialise two integers to hold the final sum
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    //Calculate sum1 starting from first element and jumping alternate element until you reach end
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=2)
        sum1 += V[i];

    //Calculate sum2 starting from second element and jumping alternate element until you reach end
    for(int i=1; i<n; i+=2)
        sum2 += V[i];

    //Print your answer
    cout << "Sum1 = " << sum1 << " " << "Sum2 = " << sum2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
Object sum[2];
size_t i = 0;
for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it, ++i)
  sum[i % 2] += *it;
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursion enthusiast might suggest:

```
typedef std::list<int>    IntList;
typedef IntList::iterator IntListIT;

void odd (IntListIT IT, int& sumEven, int& sumOdd, IntListIT ITend);
void even(IntListIT IT, int& sumEven, int& sumOdd, IntListIT ITend);


void even(IntListIT IT, int& sumEven, int& sumOdd, IntListIT ITend) {
   sumEven += *IT;
   if(++IT != ITend)
      odd(IT, sumEven, sumOdd, ITend); // tail-recursion
}

void odd(IntListIT IT, int& sumEven, int& sumOdd, IntListIT ITend) {
   sumOdd += *IT;
   if(++IT != ITend)
      even(IT, sumEven, sumOdd, ITend); // tail-recursion
}

int t209(void)
{
   IntList   intList;
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
      intList.push_back(i+1);

   int sumEven = 0;
   int sumOdd  = 0;
   even(intList.begin(), sumEven, sumOdd, intList.end());

   std::cout << "\nsumEven: " << sumEven
             << "\n sumOdd: " << sumOdd
             << "\n  total: " << (sumEven + sumOdd)
             << std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

with output

```
sumEven: 25
 sumOdd: 30
  total: 55
```

---

A different recursion enthusiast won't like the 'messy' 4 parameter recursive functions, and may suggest a class for the effort.  Surprisingly (?or did you suspect this), he is able to **eliminate(!) all** (visible) **parameters** for the class'es 2 mutually-recursive methods.

```
// class Even-Odd-Sum 
class EOSum          // wrap recursive efforts
{
public:
   EOSum(IntList& intList) :
      m_list(intList),
      m_eSum(0),
      m_oSum(0),
      m_IT(intList.begin()),
      m_ITend  (intList.end())
      { }

   ~EOSum() { m_eSum = 0; m_oSum = 0; }

   std::string operator()()
      {
         // do the math
         e();  // recursively

         // report results
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss << "\n  eSum: " << m_eSum
            << "\n  oSum: " << m_oSum
            << "\n total: " << (m_eSum + m_oSum)
            << "\n\n sizeof(this): " << sizeof(this) << " bytes.  "
            << "\nestimated total stack needed with unoptimized recursive call: "
            << DTB::digiComma(C100M*(2*sizeof(this)))
            << "\ndefault stack size Ubuntu 15.04                             :     "
            << DTB::digiComma(8*1024*1024)
            << std::endl;
         return(ss.str());
      }

   static const int C100M = 100000000;

private:
   IntList&  m_list;
   int64_t   m_eSum;
   int64_t   m_oSum;
   IntListIT m_IT;    // iterate thru the list
   IntListIT m_ITend;

   // the new and improved recursion - NO (visible) PARAMETERS
   void e()
      {
         m_eSum += *m_IT;
         if (++m_IT != m_ITend)
            o(); // tail-recursion
      }

   void o()
      {
         m_oSum += *m_IT;
         if (++m_IT != m_ITend)
            e(); // tail-recursion
      }
};

// test 
int t209b(void)
{
   std::cout << "\n\nt209b start: using EOSum::C100M = "
             << DTB::digiComma(EOSum::C100M) << " multiplier  (~10 seconds on lab005)"
             << std::endl;
   uint64_t t209bStartMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond();

   uint64_t dtorStartMS;
   {
      IntList   intList;

      {
         uint64_t startMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond();

         for (int i=0;   i<EOSum::C100M; ++i)  // use -O3 to avoid segfault - tail recursion optimized
            intList.push_back(i+1);

         uint64_t durationMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond() - startMS;
         std::cout << "\n100M list push_back's   : " << durationMS << " ms"
                   << "\n     to 'new' intList elements " << std::endl;
      }

      {
         uint64_t startMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond();

         // Ubuntu 15.04 default stack size  8 M Bytes
         //     100,000: No stack over flow
         //   1,000,000: -O0 stack overflow segfault, -O3: No segfault
         // 100,000,000: -O3: No segfault
         std::cout << EOSum(intList)() << std::endl;

         uint64_t durationMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond() - startMS;
         std::cout << "100 M recursion calls   : " << durationMS << " ms "
                   << "\n    to compute eSum, oSum, total shown above " << std::endl;
      }

      dtorStartMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond();

   }  // intList destruction at this brace

   uint64_t dtorDurationMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond() - dtorStartMS;
   std::cout << "\n100 M list item dtor's  : " << dtorDurationMS
             << "\n      to 'delete' intList elements " <<  std::endl;


   uint64_t t209bDurationMS = DTB::getSystemMillisecond() - t209bStartMS;

   std::cout << "\n t209b() duration MS    : " << t209bDurationMS << std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

In this code, the stack overflows (during the recursion) with somewhere between 100,000 to 1 M elements added to the list, when using optimization level 0 (-O0).  Note that Ubuntu 15.04's default stack is only 8 M bytes, and each method call would probably use 16 bytes (the this ptr, and return addr).

HOWEVER, the author achieved tail recursion, and because of g++ 4.9.2 compiler's impressive optimization's (at level 3, -O3), this recursion now uses a **fixed** number of stack elements! Despite the added complication of dual-mutually-recursive methods.

This code has some personal library use, so here is the output of the test:

Feel free to try this on your machine (use some simple replacement or removal of my DTB:: methods).

All durations are from my 6+ yr old Dell.

```
t209b start: using EOSum::C100M = 100,000,000 multiplier (~10 seconds on lab005)

100M list push_back's   : 6930 ms
     to 'new' intList elements 

  eSum: 2500000000000000
  oSum: 2500000050000000
 total: 5000000050000000

 sizeof(this): 8 bytes.  
estimated total stack needed with unoptimized recursive call: 1,600,000,000
default stack size Ubuntu 15.04                             :     8,388,608

100 M recursion calls   : 1320 ms 
    to compute eSum, oSum, total shown above 

100 M list item dtor's  : 2754
      to 'delete' intList elements 

 t209b() duration MS    : 11035


real  0m11.290s
user  0m8.532s
sys   0m2.556s
```

Comment: Like the idea. I wonder whether it will make sense to a beginner.

Comment: @RSahu - even non-beginners tend to resist recursion.  The OP had already chosen another answer, so I think no harm, and some readers might find it interesting.  Today I have added a class wrapped recursion.    I think, for this simple of a problem, pythonic metaphore's answer is the best (though maybe I want some more comments).  Thanks for the feedback, R.

Comment: Tail recursion is not guaranteed by C/C++ standards. Some compilers may implement it but tail recursive code is not guaranteed to be as efficient as a loop. I believe that is the biggest obstacle to using tail recursive functions in C/C++.

Comment: @RSahu - thanks, I had not heard that 'your' C/C++ compiler might not  optimize tail recursion.  But I think this is not a problem, for if your compiler won't, stack overflow happens quite quickly, and unit test should find it.  Note: I have seen optimized tail recursion to be faster, but not for all of what I have tried. And even when they do, small code changes can cause surprising performance hits.   I use recursion when it makes the problem you are solving more easily understood - readability is more important.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation where `std::valarray` might be appropriate. Assuming your goal is to add all even members and all odd members, you could do it something like this:

```
std::valarray<int> l;
// Put stuff into the array
std::valarray<int> even = l[std::slice(0, l.size() / 2, 2)]
std::valarray<int> odd  = l[std::slice(1, l.size() / 2, 2)];
int sum_of_odd = odd.sum(), sum_of_even = even.sum();
```